# Plie squats done wrong?

Tags: squats

I've been trying plie squats and wall sit ups to improve the fitness of my pelvic region. However I feel most of my pressure on my thighs a little above my knees.

Am I doing them wrong?

Comment: It's hard for us to judge the form without seeing your form. If you post a picture or video, we could more easily spot the issue.

Comment: @Alec thanks for the feedback.  I'm basically just wondering where I should be feeling the pressure

Comment: Basically, you should feel the pressure wherever your musculature is weakest. If your knees start hurting in a squat, you are generally going it wrong, but where you feel it in your legs will be different for different people, and will likely shift over time as you build your muscles up.

Comment: @SeanDuggan I don't feel it exactly on the knee, a little above it - on my quads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are supposed to mimic an adductors trainer machine but they also work the flutes muscles at the same time. Exercises like that which work antagonistic muscles together are formidable.

The exercise is supposed to work the entire lower body but targeting the adductors.

The adductors go from your inner hips all the way down to your knees. If you feel it on your lower quadriceps, that might just be a personal weakness. You will get used to it.

If it helps, it has been scientifically shown that one can increase how much a muscle grows during certain exercises and which area of that muscle grows the most just by actively thinking about it. Not sure if you are maybe familiar with the concept of mind to muscle connection. - [source](https://journals.lww.com/acsm-msse/Fulltext/2013/11000/Nonuniform_Muscle_Hypertrophy___Its_Relation_to.18.aspx)

Comment: That source you pasted seems to be the wrong link. It's about hypertrophy targeted at different parts of one muscle. I don't see how that relates to mind-muscle connection.